# Using Firebase Id Token in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

In the function that triggers when firebase user is created, I want to send a request to my rest api server.
How could I get the Firebase ID Token and attach to the api request for verifying step in my api server?

Comment: Are you trying to get the newly added user ID?

Comment: In that case why not just make the REST API call from the client directly? you have the ID token there already.